# Prove $f\equiv 0$ in the case of $f$ has finite roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on $D(0,1)$, continuous on $\overline{D}(0,1)$
> s.t $f(z)=0\quad\forall |z|=1$ and $0\leq\arg z\leq\dfrac{2\pi}{n}$
> for some $n\in\mathbb{N}^*.$
>
> a) Let
> $g(z)=\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}z\right)$. Prove
> $g(z)=0\quad\forall |z|=1$.
>
> b) Prove that $g=0$ on $D(0,1)$. Then show
> that $f=0$ on $D(0,1)$.

I have trouble in doing part $b)$. Here are my thoughts for part b):
Since $g(z)=0\quad\forall |z|=1$, we obtain $|g(z)|\leq 0\quad\forall z\in D(0,1)\Rightarrow |g(z)|=0\quad\forall z\in D(0,1)$.
If $f(z)=0$ has infinite roots in $D(0,1)$, then by Bolzano Weierstrass theorem, the exists a subsequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to a point in $D(0,1)$. Then by Identity theorem, we obtain $f\equiv 0\quad\forall z\in D(0,1)$.
I don't know how to deal with the case $f(z)=0$ has finite roots. Could someone help me or have other ways to tackle the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is not quite correct. An infinite sequence in $D(0,1)$ needs not have a subsequence converging to a point in $D(0,1)$ (consider $z_n=1-1/n$). However, you can make that argument with $\overline{D(0,1/2)}$. Let $f_k(z)=f(e^{2k\pi i/n}z)$ for $z\in \overline{D(0,1/2)}$. We have $g(z)= \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} f_k(z)$. In particular, this means, as $g\equiv 0$ on $\overline{D(0,1/2)}$, $$ \overline{D(0,1/2)}=\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} f_k^{-1}(\{0\}). $$ If all the $f^{-1}_k(\{0\})$ were finite, then $\overline{D(0,1/2)}$ was finite too, contradiction. Thus, there exists $m\in \{0, \dots, n-1\}$ such that $f_m^{-1}(\{0\})$ is infinite. Now we can use your Bolzano-Weierstrass & identity theorem argument to get $f_m \equiv 0$ on $\overline{D(0,1/2)}$, which readily implies that $f\equiv 0$ on $\overline{D(0,1/2)}$ and hence by the identity theorem $f\equiv 0$ on $D(0,1)$.

Comment: Why $f_m\equiv 0$ on $\overline{D(0,\frac{1}{2})}$ implies $f\equiv 0$ on $\overline{D(0,\frac{1}{2})}$?

Comment: Because $f(z) = f_m(e^{2\pi i /m}z)$ and $\vert z \vert = \vert e^{2\pi i /m}z \vert$ (in particular, if $z\in \overline{D(0,1/2)}$ then $e^{2\pi i /m}z \in \overline{D(0,1/2)}$).

Comment: @leemax I am missing a minus in the exponent. It should read $e^{-2\pi i/m}$ everywhere in my last comment.

Comment: @leemax Is everything clear now?